HTTPClient post binary data to Prometheus pushgateway
I am a newbie in Arduino and IoT
and using M5StickC Plus2 on Arduino IDE.
I am trying to push data to Prometheus pushgateway, but only get 400 response code.
Pushgateway only accepts binary data. Everything works fine if I do it through curl.
Here is my code:
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

WiFiClient client;
HTTPClient http;
bool httpOK = http.begin(client, "192.168.0.63", 9091, "/metrics/job/pushgateway-orangepi");

if(httpOK) {
    String msg = String("temperatura{local=\"bsb\"} 24.12\n");
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    http.addHeader("Content-Length", String(msg.length()));
    int httpResponseCode = http.POST(msg);
    http.end();
}


your code does not compile without error ... please present the minimal, compilable program that still exhibits the problem

Content-Length header must be http.addHeader("Content-Length", String(sizeof(msg)));

this can't be right. sizeof(msg) is the size of the String object which is not the size of the string managed by the String object
